# How do I specify a particular CSS class to use?

Tags: html, css, sass

I have an html block that looks like this:

```
<div id=“stage”>
     <div class=“ticker universal”>
    …
     </div>
</div>
```

With css for the classes looking like so:

```
#stage {
    position: absolute
}

.ticker.universal {          
    position: relative;
}
```

The issue I'm having is that the `.ticker.universal` position property is getting overriden by `#stage` position property. when I look at the elements in the browser console, the positon for `.ticker.universal` is actually striked out.

I have tried adding `!important` to `.ticker.universal` postion, it worked but I'm trying to avoid using `!important`.

Please what other way can I resolve this issue?

Comment: `#stage .ticker.universal, .ticker.universal {...}`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Comment: That shouldn't be an issue with the CSS and HTML you have provided because two different elements are being selected with different attributes. I noticed that the `position` style is spelt wrong in the `#stage` selector though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Follow the URL below to better solve your problem.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/position/

```css
      #stage {  
         position: relative;
         
          /*Apply your css code */
         height: 300px;
         width: 600px;
         background-color: beige;
      }

      #stage .ticker-universal {
         position: absolute;
         
          /*Apply your css code */
         height: 50px;
         width: 100px;
         background-color: coral;
         top: 0;
         left: 0;

      }
```

```html
<div id="stage">
  <div class="ticker-universal">

  </div>
</div>
```